# Relevant question on Open Data

Tags: discussion

GIS has migrated many questions to OpenData. We are happy to try to answer them!

I posted this data about how to package geojson timeseries for public accessibility. It's more appropriate on OD, but maybe some GIS experts will have good ideas. thanks!

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16284/what-is-an-effective-way-to-share-many-geojsons-that-are-a-timeseries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a link to your Open Data question that seeks help from GIS users would be more appropriately posted in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) because it is about a specific question from a Main site rather than being about the "[workings and policies of GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)".

I have taken the liberty of posting that [Open Data question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53894064#53894064) in our chat room already.